# Passing Parameters To Soap Request

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to pass a couple of parameters to a SOAP service.  I try doing this at the very end of the code block listed below.  For some reason I cannot get this to work.  Can someone please help me out a little bit.  Thanks in advance!

```
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">"
                         "<soap12:Body>"
                         "<UserLogin xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                         "<username>string</username>"
                         "<password>string</password>"
                         "</UserLogin>"
                         "</soap12:Body>"
                         "</soap12:Envelope>, %@, %@", txtUsername.text, txtPassword.text];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                         "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">"
                         "<soap12:Body>"
                         "<UserLogin xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                         "<username>%@</username>"
                         "<password>%@</password>"
                         "</UserLogin>"
                         "</soap12:Body>"
                         "</soap12:Envelope>", txtUsername.text, txtPassword.text];
```